# Why am I getting duplicate <a> tags?

Tags: php, html

I'm using the bootstrap "pager" found in the pagination section.

Here is what I'm using to load the HTML of it in PHP:

```php
echo "<ul class='pager'>";
echo ($total > $lim) ? "<li class='previous'>" : "<li class='previous disabled'>";
echo ($total > $lim) ? "<a href='#status' onclick='getStatuses(" . (($lim+10)/10) . ")'>&larr; Older</a>" : "<a>&larr; Older</a>";
echo "</li>";
echo ($lim == 10) ? "<li class='next disabled'>" : "<li class='next'>";
echo ($lim == 10) ? "<a>Newer &rarr;</a>" : "<a href='#status' onclick='getStatuses(" . (($lim-10)/10) . ")'>Newer &rarr;</a>";
echo "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

Now, when I actually load this, it returns like this:

```html
<ul class="pager">
<a></a>
<li class="previous disabled">
<a></a>
<a>← Older</a>
</li>
<li class="next disabled">
<a>Newer →</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

There are 2 what seem to be random `<a></a>` tags. How can I get rid of these? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Validate your HTML. That is not the actual HTML your PHP produced, but the HTML your browser turned it into, because your HTML has a validation error before this block.

Comment: View your actual page source. Don't rely on your browser's DOM inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing out a bunch of HTML from PHP usually leads to code comprehension difficulties. Better to drop out of the PHP context for the most part, for example

```
// drop out of PHP
?>
<ul class="pager">
    <?php if ($total > $lim) : ?>
        <li class="previous">
            <a href="#status" onclick="getStatuses(<?= ($lim+10)/10 ?>)">&larr; Older</a>
        </li>
    <?php else : ?>
        <li class="previous disabled">
            <a>&larr; Older</a>
        </li>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if ($lim == 10) : ?>
        <li class="next disabled">
            <a>Newer &rarr;</a>
        </li>
    <?php else : ?>
        <li class="next">
            <a href="#status" onclick="getStatuses(<?= ($lim-10)/10 ?>)">Newer &rarr;</a>
        </li>
    <?php endif ?>
</ul>

<?php
// and now back to PHP
```

Answer (score -1):

Agreed with Phil, but my guess would be the &larr or the fact that you don't have parenthesis around your ternary expressions. Try this:

```
echo "<ul class='pager'>";
echo (($total > $lim) ? "<li class='previous'>" : "<li class='previous disabled'>");
echo (($total > $lim) ? "<a href='#status' onclick='getStatuses(" . (($lim+10)/10) . ")'> Older</a>" : "<a> Older</a>");
echo "</li>";
echo (($lim == 10) ? "<li class='next disabled'>" : "<li class='next'>");
echo (($lim == 10) ? "<a>Newer &rarr;</a>" : "<a href='#status' onclick='getStatuses(" . (($lim-10)/10) . ")'>Newer</a>");
echo "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: `echo condition ? true response : false response` works just fine in PHP. You don't even need parentheses around the condition, eg `echo 1 == 2 ? 'a' : 'b'`. Also, `&larr;` ( ← ) and `&rarr;` ( → ) are perfectly valid HTML entities